# A question on emission spectrum and two-time correlation function

Tags: quantum-optics, correlation-functions, photon-emission

Here, the expression of the emission spectrum is
$$S(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\langle A^\dagger(t+\tau)A(t) \rangle e^{-i\omega\tau}\text{d}\tau=2\Re\left\{\int_{0}^{\infty}\langle A^\dagger(t+\tau)A(t) \rangle e^{-i\omega\tau} \text{d}\tau\right\},$$
and the two-time correlation function, i.e. the Fourier inverse transform of the spectrum, is
$$C_A(\tau)=\langle A^\dagger(t+\tau)A(t) \rangle .$$
When we consider $t\to+\infty$, the condition corresponds to the steady-state emission spectrum and correlation function.

Now, I consider a simple model, and its Lindblad master equation is
$$\frac{\text{d}\rho}{\text{d}t}=-i[\Omega(\sigma+\sigma^\dagger),\rho]+\frac{\gamma}{2}[2\sigma\rho\sigma^\dagger-\sigma^\dagger\sigma \rho-\rho\sigma^\dagger\sigma],$$
where $\sigma(=|g\rangle\langle e|)$ denotes the lowering operator of the two-level atom, $\Omega$ is the driving strength, and $\gamma$ is the atomic decay rate. Then, I will solve the master equation based on QuTiP simulation, and the corresponding Python code appears as follows.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import qutip as qt

# The system parameters
gam = 2
Ome = gam / 4

# The lowering operator of the two-level atom
sm = qt.sigma()

# The system Hamiltonian
H = Ome * (sm + sm.dag())

# The atomic decay rate
c_ops = [np.sqrt(gam) * sm]

# Calculating the two-time correlation function in the steady state

tlist = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
C_a = qt.correlation_2op_1t(H, None, tlist, c_ops, sm.dag(), sm)

# Calculating the emission spectrum in the steady state

wlist = np.linspace(-4, 4, 1000)
S = qt.spectrum(H, wlist, c_ops, sm.dag(), sm)

# drawing 
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(tlist, np.real(C_a), 'blue', label=r'$C_\sigma(\tau)$')
plt.xlabel(r'$t$')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(wlist, np.real(S), 'red', label=r'$S(\omega)$')
plt.xlabel(r'$\omega$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The output is shown below:
[image]

What I don't understand is that the two-time correlation function $C_\sigma(\tau)$ obviously approaches a fixed value ($\approx0.111$) when $\tau$ is large ($\tau>10$), but its emission spectrum is still a finite value. Notably, the Fourier transform of the two-time correlation function about frequency $\omega$ should be a $\delta$ function due to $C_\sigma(\tau\gg1)\approx 0.111$.

Finally, the descriptions of the two functions `spectrum` and `correlation_2op_1t` in QuTiP are as follows.
[image]
[image]